# Woocommerce new customer email to store manager

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

### Option 1

I'm trying to override the Woocommerce template structure in the following way: 
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/.

The file I'm trying to override is: your_template_directory/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.

At the end of this file I added the following code:

```
<?php do_action( 'new_customer_registered', $user_login ); ?>
In functions.php add this:

function new_customer_registered_send_email_admin($user_login) {
  ob_start();
  do_action('woocommerce_email_header', 'New customer registered');
  $email_header = ob_get_clean();
  ob_start();
  do_action('woocommerce_email_footer');
  $email_footer = ob_get_clean();

  woocommerce_mail(
    get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
    get_bloginfo('name').' - New customer registered',
    $email_header.'<p>The user '.esc_html( $user_login ).' is registered to the website</p>'.$email_footer
  );
}
add_action('new_customer_registered', 'new_customer_registered_send_email_admin');
```

This code is to send an e-mail to the admin of the website. The admin_email is retrieved by the `get_bloginfo` function. However, I'm trying to send the e-mail to the **store manager** instead. Any idea what function or code should be used in this case?

### Option 2

Another option could be to add the following code to the functions.php file and adapt this so it sends a notification to the store manager instead of the admin:

```
/**
 * Notify admin when a new customer account is created
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'woocommerce_created_customer_admin_notification' );
function woocommerce_created_customer_admin_notification( $customer_id ) {
  wp_send_new_user_notifications( $customer_id, 'admin' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this as follows. I've added the following code in my `functions.php` file:

```
/* SEND NEW CUSTOMER EMAIL TO KILIKILI */
/* --- */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    if ($object == 'customer_new_account') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: Store manager name <storemanager@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```